# We have a box with m blue balls and n red balls ($n \lt m$). We bet r dollars that we will randomly pick a red ball....

Tags: probability, solution-verification, problem-solving

> We have a box with m blue balls and n red balls ($n \lt m$). We bet r dollars that we will randomly pick a red ball. If we get a red ball we win k times the money we bet. If not, we lose the money wagered. Determine k so that the expected profit is favorable to the bettor.

This exercise is about probability, but I can't think of a way to use probability to solve it.

I could only think of this:

Total number of balls n+m = t.

The probability of getting a blue ball is $\frac{m}{t}$ and the probability of getting a red ball is $\frac{n}{t}$ $P[blue] + P[red] = \frac{m}{t} + \frac{n}{t} = 1$ as $n \lt  m$ we know that $P[blue] = xP[red ]$ where x is a number greater than 1, if $x = \frac{m}{n}$ then $k = x+1 = (\frac{m}{n} + 1)\cdot P[red] \gt P[blue] $

I have the feeling that I'm missing something (a lot), but I'm stuck.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each bet, you either obtain $k\cdot r$ dollars when you pick the red ball, or you lose $r$ dollars if you pick the blue ball. So, using your notation, the expected payout value from a single bet is:
$$
P[red]\cdot (k\cdot r) + P[blue]\cdot (-r) = \frac{n\cdot k\cdot r}{m+n} - \frac{m\cdot r}{m+n} = \frac{r}{m+n}(n\cdot k-m)
$$

This is the expected payout, i.e. the average payout if you repeat the bet a number of times. For the bet to be profitable to the better, the expected payout must be positive - so you will on average earn money instead of losing it. So we just need to solve an inequality for $k$:
$$
\frac{r}{m+n}(n\cdot k-m) > 0
$$
$$
n\cdot k - m > 0
$$
$$
k > \frac{m}{n}
$$
We of course assume that $r$ and $n$ are positive.

Comment: @Bruno Please mark the answer as accepted if you are satisfied with my explanation.

Comment: apologies for the delay.